# Programming Usb Connection with Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, connection, usb

I've started a project on Andorid, but I don't know NDK very much. I want to send custom data as per receiving message on usb port. I saw some applications that can send/recieve custom data on usb port if the phone is in recovery. I've programmed usb connection in windows before. But I haven't any clue where should I start in android. Is there any documentation for usb programming for android? If NDK isn't suitable to implement this, which options do I have? It is not important if the application is device specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues are more of system architecture and permission, an area where the NDK offers little in excess of the SDK.

Android does not really support (direct) custom use of the USB port, at least when the device is connected to a computer (there are some recent options when the device is hosting a USB  peripheral).  What is possible in recovery mode is essentially irrelevant, unless you want to make substantial modifications to the installation of Android running on your device.

Generally, the only practical way to do application-level communication between the device and a hosting PC is to use the IP networking paradigm over the USB cable.  You do this either by enabling USB debugging on the device and installing much of the android SDK on the PC, or by enabling some forms of tethering which may create a general network as a side effect.

For the SDK method, read up on adb port forwards, including the limitation that the PC side must initiate the connection.

It may also be possible to create custom drivers which get a PC to pretend to be an android accessory kit (ADK) circuit and use the apis related to that.

Unfortunately, pretty much all of these ideas are more suitable for developers/power users, than for general consumer application.  For consumer apps, most developers ignore the USB cable and do IP networking over WIFI, requiring the user to put the device and the PC on the same network, or proxy through an Internet server visible to both the PC and the device's mobile network.